# How to think of a script that auto widens a search field when a username next to it gets too long

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal is simple when a username gets too long on an account drop down menu how to make the search field reduce in width to make room for the longer name; the same is true when the name is short, how to make the form field fill up the empty space when a name is shorter.

I've started a pen here: http://codepen.io/MARS/pen/qtJsr

I'll be working on it throughout the day so there's no JS there now, but really i'm looking for ideas more than someone telling me exactly how to do it.

In pseudo code i'm guessing it would be something like this:

```
 var username = $('#usernameID").length();
 var search   = $('#searchFieldId');

 if(username > 34) {
   make search bar this width (can be fixed because we have a cap of 34 characters so it will never get bigger than that)
} 

if(username < 34){
  make search field as wide as need be to be next to the elements without there being significant space
}
```

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

I'm almost thinking a while statement might be best but i'm new to javascript and my thinking is slow when putting the dots together.

There are icon placeholders that are to the right of the form field and to the left of the username, this is not so much part of the problem as it is something i need to account for.

Can anyone provide any suggestions? Thanks.

SOLUTION CODE THAT WORKED:

```
var userWidth = $('#userOptions');
var searchField = $('#txtFamilySearch');
var icons = $('.icons');

$('#txtFamilySearch').css("width", 740 - (userWidth.width() + icons.width()));
```

Comment: Can't you just ellipsis the overflow?

Comment: @epascarello do you mean add an overflow-y property to the element so that the name won't go past it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: @epascarello that's a neat solution and I wasn't even aware of some of these properties. Unfortunately it's not exactly what i need but i'll keep it in mind for other uses. Thanks.

Comment: @epascarello I actually ended up using this property in tandem with a JS solution, thanks for the tip I had not idea that property was available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you were looking for ideas more so than answers. If I was writing this page I would first set a specific width on the Search bar and the Username field. This way the two fields combined add up to a specific width: 700px Search, 200px Username = 900px work space. Then create an onload call on the body tag to run a function that checks the width of the username. So the username will be in a span with an id of "username"

```
function onloadFunct() {
    var userLength = document.getElementById("username").innerHTML.length();
    if (userLength > x) {
        // we want the search to shrink
        var Y = userLength - standardLength;
        // I get the number of characters past what the textbox can normally hold
        var Z = Y * pixelsPerCharacter;
        // I multiply the excess characters by the estimated space they will take up
        document.getElementById("search").width = document.getElementById("search").width - Z;
        document.getElementById("username").width = document.getElementById("username").width + Z;
    } else {
        // we want the search to grow
        // same as above but I reverse the - and + signs 
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, the point of keeping both the search bar and the username field equal to a specific width is to avoid taking up the space that is needed for the icon placeholders.

Example variables:
`standardLength = 40; // 40 characters can fit comfortably within the 200 space`
`pixelsPerCharacter = 5; // each character will take up about 5 pixels, so for every character past the bounds we will add 5`

ALTERNATIVELY: 
You can take off the width  of username field, and after the page has loaded use

```
javascript: document.getElementById("search").width = 900 - document.getElementById("username").width;
```

Comment: Updated the answer, I recommend the Alternative part. Assuming the width and pixels per character is impractical and not very efficient.

Comment: ok, i'm working through your solution now and I had a question. If .innerHTML() or .html() only grabs "the first element in the set of matched elements" according to the jQuery API, so my question is since my text is not within an another HTML element like a <p>, <a> or <span> but rather just floating within the #userOptions id then how will .innerHTML know to grab only the length of the text. Because inside of the #userOptions there is also an SVG and a UL, does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: You put the username in a span with an id of username (I wrote that right above the code snippit, sorry for confusion)

Comment: Wherever on your page you are writing the username you will encapsulate that and only that in a span. Though I recommend the alternative suggestion. You simply grab the width of the #userOptions

Answer (score 0):

I'm lazy to write full solution. I think, that you should use size property of input. If size is used, then you shouldn't think about pixel length of input and overall width; here, only left field rules

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width:500px">
            <input size="30" id="fname" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name"></input>
            <input size="30" id="lname" type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name"></input>
        </div>
        <script>
            var fname   = document.getElementById('fname'),
                lname   = document.getElementById('lname'),
                fSize   = fname.size,
                lSize   = lname.size;

            document
                .getElementById('fname')
                .addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
                    var len = this.value.length;
                    if (len > fSize) {
                        this.size += 1;
                        lname.size -= 1;
                    }
                });
            document.getElementById('lname').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
                alert('lname');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach on similar use cases is like:

- create/get/copy element with auto width
- add element to dom
- get width of the rendered element
- do whatever you want to other elements depending on the width
- Note: you would eventually have to consider margin and padding.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working JS fiddle with the JavaScript:

http://jsbin.com/lorajuza/7/edit?js

Code:

> $('#txtFamilySearch').on('keydown', function() {
>
> ```
>  var input = $(this),
>  inputWidth = input.val().length;
>
>  if ( inputWidth > 34 ) {
>
> input.attr('size', inputWidth );
>    }
>  else {
> input.attr('size', 50)
> ```
>
> } 
>   });

You will need to add responsive CSS to ensure the buttons stay on the same line. I would also set a max limit for the input size, but that's up to you.